# English verbs requiring PP

Tags: syntax, terminology, verbs, prepositions

Are there a set of English verbs that require a prepositional phrase? For example:

"The set **consists** of A and B." = GOOD

"The set **consists**" = BAD

Is there a name for this type of verb? They seem to be different than 'transitive' which relies on a direct object. To clarify, I'm not asking about verb-particle (phrasal verb relations); I'm only interested in verb-PP.

Comment: Such verbs are intransitive. I’m not aware of any name for this type, the linguists just say the verb “subcategorises for a PP.”

Comment: Hmm. I thought an intransitive verb must be able to stand alone without a direct object, which this can not.

Comment: Maybe search in _phrasal verbs_; **chip in, figure out, hand down/in**

Comment: @JoopEggen I've already analyzed 6900 phrasal verbs. That's why my question explicitly states that **I'm not asking about phrasal verbs**.  :)

Comment: @jeffschneider apologies; I think there might be some linguistic (_semantic_?) category for verbs like **consist** and **result** but that eludes my meager linguistic knowledge.

Comment: @Atamiri I found these categories: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/s0896251/XMG-basedXTAG/noweb/VerbFamilies.html I see your point. The verb class is labeled by transitivity, argument type and optional/mandated, for example, "Intransitive with PP: n0Vpn1".

Comment: @jeffschneider No, a verb is intransitive if it can’t take a direct object. A PP can still be required by an intransitive verb’s valency frame.